# query date by month and year with hibernate from database

Tags: java, hibernate, date

i have a named query where I want to fetch all records where year and month of a parameter match the database entry:

```
@NamedQuery(
        name = entries.queryX,
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT t from entries t " +
        "where MONTH(t.myMonth) = :month " +
        "and YEAR(t.myMonth) = :year "
)
```

The value "myMonth" in table entries is a YearMonth:

```
@Column(name = "MY_MONTH", precision = 7)
private YearMonth myMonth;
```

I set the query parameters as follows:

```
query.setParameter("month", date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
query.setParameter("year", date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

However, this approach does not work... Is there any other way to implement what I want to search for?

Comment: Why is myMonth a String and not a LocalDate? MONTH and YEAR does only work with Dates

Comment: the date comes as "yyyy-MM". Would it work with YearMonth as well?

Comment: When you can use the modern `YearMonth`, why also use the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar`? Allow me to suggest that you go all-in on [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I changed the whole dates to LocalDate in order not to design an additional converter for YearDate.
The Calendar types are design decisions from prior developer colleagues. I just took over now. Believe me, there is much more that should get refactored. ;)